# Visual Basic - Autoclicker that doesn't use the cursor

Tags: google-chrome, vba, visual-studio-2012, element, executable

So what I'm trying to make is something like this:

1).exe file has a web browser
2)web browser directs you to a button
3)i use the code "Dim elements = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("nupuke420_kitchen")" to focus on the button

But that code was all i found from research. Can anyone please guide me on how do I actually make my program click on it every 3 milliseconds? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: "elements.InvokeMember("click")